# Array of Associations for a Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there any way to make an array of the associations for a specific Model?

```
#app/models/users.rb
class Users < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :things
has_many :other_things

@associations[ things, other_things ]
```

So that you can use something like this:

```
#app/models/users.rb
@associations.select {|s| (s.count > 0)}
```

to see if the Model has at least one of the associations. This will be EXTREMELY useful in my application, and make abstracting out a lot of the behavior I am trying to implement possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there's an elegant way to do this, but one solution would be to create a method that just wraps your associations in an array:

```
def array_of_associations
  [things, other_things]
end
```

Your code, as above, would then work:

```
model_instance.array_of_associations.select {|s| s.count > 0}
```

This, of course, is at the instance level, but it shouldn't be too complicated to extract it to the class level as a scope or class method.

Answer (score -1):

You can add your two associations like two arrays

```
def all_things
  things + other_things
end
```

Now when you call all_things you have an array with things and other_things.

But be careful if things and other_things are different model.